# Sonata Admin - how to change default /admin prefix

Tags: symfony, routes, sonata-admin

I've stumbled upon an issue, and I can't find a solution to it.

I want to change default Sonata `/admin` URL path prefix to something else.
I've tried to change `routing.yml` routes `admin` and `_sonata_admin` to something other than `/admin`, but still, it's remain the default admin panel path. Really confusing.

How to change that default `/admin` path?

**UPDATE** (`routing.yml` listing):

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

sonata_user_profile_show:
    resource: "@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml"

admin:
    resource: '@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml'
    prefix:   /admin

sonata_user:
    resource: '@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/admin_security.xml'
    prefix:   /admin

_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
    type:     sonata_admin
    prefix:   /admin
    defaults:
        _locale: "%locale%"
```

Comment: this happens still after clear cache ?

Comment: Sure. I did `cache:clear`.

Comment: Changing prefix works fine for me in routing.yml for route _admin. Removed cache completely with rm -Rf though

Comment: Did that. Please, see my update with `routing.yml` file, maybe I did something wrong? Everything else works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change default admin prefix in url you need to update in `routing.yml` first which i guess by reading comments you already have done, second thing to you need change this in `security.yml` also by changing the admin firewall pattern and `access_control` rules, if needed clear your cache too after applying below changes

### Routing

```
admin_area:
    resource: "@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml"
    prefix: /panel

_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
    type: sonata_admin
    prefix: /panel

sonata_user:
    resource: '@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/admin_security.xml'
    prefix: /panel
```

### Firewall

```
security:
    firewalls:
        admin:
            pattern:            /panel(.*)
            context:            user
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     sonata_user_admin_security_login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     sonata_user_admin_security_check
                failure_path:   null
            logout:
                path:           sonata_user_admin_security_logout
                target:         sonata_user_admin_security_login
            anonymous:          true

    access_control:

        # Admin login page needs to be access without credential
        - { path: ^/panel/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/panel/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/panel/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/panel/, role: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN] }
```

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid i think your version truee

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid: Thank you for posting this answer, I'll check it out tomorrow morning.

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid: This setup helped, but I'm sure I did that before... Probably, cosmic rays : ) Anyway, this is a working solution.